# how to use extarrows package in mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

I want to use [extarrows package](https://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/extarrows/extarrows-test.pdf) to dispaly stretchable arrow in mathjax，

```
\xLongleftarrows
\xLongrightarrows
...
```

any ideas?
or any other way for stretchable arrow in mathjax?

Comment: Did you read the mathjax docs? What do they say about doing this?

Comment: I try to use macros: `macros: { xLeftrightarrow: ['\\ext@arrow 0099\\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}', 2] }` ,but not work

Comment: Remember that this is not a general help forum, there are [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): If you've written code, explain why you thought that code should have worked, and explain what it does instead, and what you've already done to debug the problem and/or (re)search the solution. Also note that Mathjax has a community forum on https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users: have you already asked there?

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I'm a newor to stackoverflow. For some reason, i can't use google, [https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users)  is not accessible for me. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text/85115#85115) is worked in latex editor, but not work in [mathjax](https://codepen.io/shawchen08/pen/poPebzZ)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i find this code works:

```
$$  A \require{mathtools}\xLeftrightarrow[longlong-sub-text]{longlong-sup-text} B  $$
```